# Получение информации об атрибутах таблицы из скрипта TSQL

Tags: c#, sql

Мне нужно получать информацию об атрибутах таблицы (имя, тип, null/not null, constraints) из `CREATE TABLE` скрипта, но я так и не смог найти никаких библиотек или фреймворков для этого. Есть ли какие то способы это сделать без ручного парсинга?

Моя программа не использует базу данных. Информация об атрибутах должна получаться из самого текста скрипта.

Например из следующего скрипта

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[person](
    [id] [int] NOT NULL ,
    [Name] [VARCHAR](1) NULL,
    [fk] [int] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_person] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id])
)
```

Должна быть получена примерно такая информация. (для примера, чтобы было понятнее)

```
Table table.name = ParseResult.TableName; //"person"
Attribute a0 = ParseResult.Attr[0]; //Attribute{"id", "int" "NOT NULL", "PK"}
Attribute a1 = ParseResult.Attr[1]; 
Attribute a2 = ParseResult.Attr[2];
```

Comment: Задача очень специфическая, готовую библиотеку вы вряд ли найдете. Лучшее, что вы можете сделать, это создать таблицу на каком-нибудь sql-сервере, после чего с помощью запросов к системным таблицам получить всю необходимую информацию об этой таблице

Comment: Я не шарю в БД, но искать наверное надо что-то типа "TSQL get table schema".

Comment: Смотрите системные таблицы вашей бд. Но вообще задача редкая у вас, есть вероятность что вы что то делаете не так в своем ПО, если вам надо лазать в системные таблицы.

Comment: Запрос в гугл: "c# sql parser". Первые две ссылки: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/589096/5045688), [2](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/azure-sql/programmatically-parsing-transact-sql-t-sql-with-the-scriptdom-parser/) - и там ещё смотрите ссылки. Вроде, можно найти решение

Comment: В каждой СУБД свои средства хранения метаданных, и соответственно свои средства и способы их получения.

Comment: information_schema.columns - стандартное представление метаданных.

Comment: Лю-ю-юди! Автор не из БД хочет получить инфу, а сам sql-запрос распарсить! По-моему, так. Но пусть он уточнит.

Comment: Чтобы уточнить для чего это нужно, я делаю программу для создания диаграмм баз данных и одна из возможностей - генерация диаграммы из `CREATE TABLE` скрипта. То есть мне нужно не из базы брать инфу, а из файла. То бишь самого текста скрипта.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov эти парсеры не обладают нужным функционалом. Они получают информацию об отдельном токене, а не о всей таблице.

Comment: Опишите это подробнее в вопросе. Отредактируйте его.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Парсить семантику скрипта - сложное и неблагодарное дело.

По советам из комментариев создал локальную базу, после чего выполняю на ней скрипт и получаю информацию о созданных сущностях через системные таблицы.